# I'm trying to make a copy of "C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs\Amcache.hve" while in-use, with no third party tools (airgap)

Tags: windows

I'm trying to make a copy of "C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs\Amcache.hve" on a live system (without downtime) but it's in use.

Can `REG SAVE` or anything similar manage this? It can save other hives, but seemingly only by hive paths like `HKLM/...`

I'm doing computer forensics and would normally use other tools to copy this, but is there anything native to windows that can do it?

Comment: Can't you image this live system to a bare metal image and then work with that instead of the live system?

Comment: @trinsic no physical access. Air-gap scenario, but only with internal ssh / rdp access within the environment. It's silliness for sure. So I can't use hobocopy or any tools meant for this. Wondering if there's any Windows native tricks for it.

Comment: @trinsic maybe these? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc788055(v=ws.11) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc772172(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 0):

I almost have an answer, possibly, through the [Volume Shadow Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service) Service.

Two tools are available natively to work with the service:

- [Vssadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc754968(v=ws.11))
- [Diskshadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc772172(v=ws.11))

In theory (if I understand what the Volume Shadow Copy Service does) based on the docs, I should be able to use these commands to achieve a clone of a live disk in use, and then access that clone:

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=c:
diskshadow
listshadows all
expose <ShadowID> z:
```

Haven't had a chance to test. Will update.